# Eclipse Luna - Disable Subversive install connectors popup

Tags: eclipse, svn, popup, subclipse, connector

I have installed Subclipse in Eclipse Luna to be able to work with SVN repositories. I can commit, update, etc. But when I start Eclipse there's an annoying popup that asks me to install a Subversive connector. How can I disable that popup? And what's about this Subversive connector if I already installed Subclipse and can work normally with SVN repositories?

This is the popup that shows when I start Eclipse:
[Annoying popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGhVe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must choose a connector to make Subversive work. The base Subversive code does not contain any code to actually connect to a SVN repository.

Note that Subclipse and Subversive are two separate implementations of SVN for Eclipse. You only need one of them installed.

Comment: Hello Greg, I have installed Subclipse and already working with svn repositories, that's why I don't understand why it still asks me to install a connector. The SVN functionallity is working, I can download projects, update, commit, put comments in my commits, add new files to the repository, etc.

Comment: Subclipse is different from Subversive. You appear to have also installed Subversive. For some reason there are two separate SVN implementations for Eclipse.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I checked in my preferences and in Team I had two different SVN options. Went to my installed software and yes, there were Subclipse and Subversion export plugin.

Comment: I uninstalled Subversive plugins and the popup doesn't show anymore. Thanks Greg.